# Parse through a JSON in node/javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js

can anyone help me parse through a json
i want to read through this json

```
"GB": {
        "0005000010105A00": {
            "title_id": "0005000010105A00",
            "eshop_id": "20010000000023",
            "product_code": "WUP-N-HNNA",
            "name": "Netflix",
            "platform": 124,
            "platform_device": "WUP",
            "publisher": 584,
            "banner_url": "https://kanzashi-wup.cdn.nintendo.net/i/51fdaa8b1ebb0ea9119b3ccd6456e641c45f5a2d9065f29b5c48f9e2b4b7127e.jpg",
            "icon_url": "https://kanzashi-wup.cdn.nintendo.net/i/131a440b27b50e257cfdad2dc79b4ff4cb8d9b8a2b683efb0884a608430841f6.jpg",
            "data_size": "63963276",
            "description": "Instantly watch movies and TV episodes streaming from Netflix right to your TV via your Wii U console. Watch as often as you want, anytime you want. Download and install Netflix to get started. New Netflix members can start their one-month free trial today. Cancel anytime. Netflix membership required. Service only available in certain countries. Visit netflix.com for details. Subscription required.",
            "availability": {
                "eshop": true,
                "retail": false,
                "dates": {
                    "eshop": "2012-11-29",
                    "retail": null
                }
            },
            "screenshots": [
                "https://kanzashi-wup.cdn.nintendo.net/i/638462c1705a0218f4f51b2f89c087ca2ad991554124a8c286d6ba42dc4e2d7d.jpg",
                "https://kanzashi-wup.cdn.nintendo.net/i/93823895f675328ab5018ed6909532eb5d7e267b8ff7d7d2ef743c35dd540475.jpg",
                "https://kanzashi-wup.cdn.nintendo.net/i/fd193363aeb094f839ca58c23753b41a52e11d3c8e49652eff61632218c9bb6d.jpg"
            ],
            "movies": []
        },
```

And just get the ID
is there anyway to look for the name and get the ID back? (the id is the 0005000010105A00)
thanks!

EDIT

I have this now,

```
let myObject = JSON.parse("/Users/yavda/python/intermediate/qrcode/data.json");

// Create our id variable.  If we don't find the desired name, id will be undefined.
function getId (name) {
  let id;
  Object.entries(myObject.GB).forEach(([key,obj]) => {
    if (obj.name === name) {
      id = key;
    }
  });
  return id;
}

// now netflixId will be the desired id, or undefined if there's no such name found.
let netflixId = getId('Netflix');
console.log(netflixId)
```

but now it throws this error

```
undefined:1
/Users/yavda/python/intermediate/qrcode/data.json
^

SyntaxError: Unexpected token / in JSON at position 0
    at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/yavda/python/intermediate/qrcode/test.js:2:21)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1254:14)
    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1308:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1117:32)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:958:12)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:81:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47

Node.js v18.16.0
```

So it thinks the ID is undefined and its throwing another error, I looked around and this probably means I have an invalid json but I used the same json with as similar program in python and it worked fine.

Comment: I think what you've got there is a JavaScript object and not "a JSON".

Comment: Is this all of the data or just a subset? Answers will be different depending on that information.

Comment: If some one posted a answer that works for you, please mark that as answer and do not just copy the provided code to your question with a "edit" note!

Comment: `JSON.parse(...)` does not take a path to a json file, instead it parses a string, Read your json file as string, and pass that to `JSON.parse()`. Your path `/Users/yavda/python/intermediate/qrcode/data.json` is simply no valid json. Thats why you get the error.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to make a few assumptions to try to help you.

First, I'm guessing you have an object like this:

```json
{
  "GB": {
    ...
  }
}
```

where each entry in the "GB" object is an object with the form you described.

If so, here's how I would select the object you provided and return it's "id" (typically called a "key" in the JavaScript community).

```
// Get your json data from somewhere like a file or URL and parse it into an object.
let myObject = JSON.parse(myJsonData);

// Create our id variable.  If we don't find the desired name, id will be undefined.
function getId (name) {
  let id;
  Object.entries(myObject.GB).forEach(([key,obj]) => {
    if (obj.name === name) {
      id = key;
    }
  });
  return id;
}

// now netflixId will be the desired id, or undefined if there's no such name found.
let netflixId = getId('Netflix');
```

I hope that helps.

For future reference, you'll do better posting what you've tried already.

Comment: I edited the question with the new error

Answer (score 0):

If your JSON is in a .json file, you can access it in code with `require`:

```
const filename = 'your-file-name'
const data = require(filename)
```

Then use Sir Robert's answer to get the ID, or [install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v6/commands/npm-install) and then use the very popular lodash library's [get](https://lodash.com/docs/4.17.15#get) function:

```
const _ = require('lodash')

const filename = 'your-file-name'
const data = require(filename)

const netflixId = _.get(data, 'ID')
```